# How can I authenticate mobile clients using OAuth and .Net Core Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, asp.net-core-2.0, openiddict

I've been trying for a while now to implement mobile authentication so clients can use their phones to authenticate to my .NET Core website.  To be clear, the exact setup I am trying to achieve is this:

1. Clients can either register on website or phone app
2. Clients can also login on website or phone app
3. After authentication, phone app users can access protected API's

Because I believe that all of the above result in a "token" (I believe this is JWT from my research) being sent to the device, I also want to minimise the amount of repeated logins that the client has to do.  I believe that this means that my flow has to use "refresh tokens" so the client can re-request valid JWT tokens in the event that the existing tokens become out of date.

I've kept at the above for quite some time and I've always felt like I'm over complicating the implementation.  Setting up the above in a trivial .NET Core application usually means I install OpenIddict, configure the password flow, enable refresh tokens, set up custom controllers to facilitate the registration/login flow.  And then on the phone app side, store the token somewhere, and inject it into future http requests if available.  This is without integrating the above with .NET Core identity, so authenticated users can access their own details like email etc.  All the examples online that I have seen show OpenIddict being used to make the above happen but don't show how to then make that work with .NET Core Identity.

So, how can I make a .NET core website that will let people authenticate to it on mobile clients?  Do I have to use something like OpenIddict or is there a simpler path I am missing?

Comment: Take a look at the `authorization_code` OAuth flow. It basically redirects your app users to a login page, where they exchange their credentials to a access_code, then your mobile app exchanges that with an `access_token`+ `refresh_token`. As long the refresh token is valid, the user does not need to re-authenticate. You can take a look at it here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#authorization-code

Comment: In my mind I was leaning towards the "password flow" due to it being easier... but third party libraries etc appear to have better support for authorization_code flow.  I'll give that a try, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to use something like OpenIddict or is there a simpler path I am missing?

Using an OpenID Connect server and the code flow - ideally, with proof key for code exchange - is certainly your best option and it matches all your requirements.

If you prefer managed implementations, you can take a look at the offering of identity providers like Azure AD, Okta or Auth0.

Comment: It's probably entirely because I lack the ability to implement a working OpenIddict implementation in my .net core application, but I simply don't understand why configuring and setting up OpenIddict in a new .net core application is as difficult as what it currently is.  My experience has been install the package, configure Startup.cs with the things I want, copy the controller code from the sample on github and hit the go button and hope that it works.  Again this is far more likely a reflection on me then it is on OpenIddict.

Comment: I feel like if OpenIddict exposed a simpler setup option that could configure it in the Startup.cs, and maybe used something like Razor View Libraries for the required visual things, that would be amazing.  Even if this path supported the most basic flow (like password flow with refresh tokens) it would still be better than people trying to implement something like OpenIddict, giving up, and storing user/pass for future logins instead.  This library is great though and I thank you very much for creating it and supporting it (even in the face of people like me squealing "its too hard!") :)

Comment: It's pretty much how the first OpenIddict bits used to work, but it was too limited and not extensible enough. It's also how Identity UI work, but feedback demonstrated this was a poor approach and it's likely Identity UI will be abandoned at some point. If you want a zero-code experience, you may want to give OrchardCore's OpenID module, which is based on OpenIddict.